# Retrieving Data using Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

Retrieving data using Curl in PHP.

I use the code below to post data to API it works:

```
$data_string = array("info_id" => "JPT00vZmVmMz", "info" => "my first info"); 
$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "mysite.com/info", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: Bearer mybear_id", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
echo $response; 
}
```

Now I want to get/retrieve the info back using the info_id. For this I have substituted `POST` for `GET` METHOD as in this line below

`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",`  but its no working hence the code below for retrieval. It seems the `info_id` is not submitted to enable data retrieval.

Can someone help me fix the issue? Thanks

```
$data_string = array("info_id" => "JPT00vZmVmMz"); 
$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "mysite.com/info", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: Bearer mybear_id", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
echo $response; 
}
```

Comment: It is not working? Do you get any error message or does the endpoint return a empty response? You need to be more specific. Does the info endpoint take a POST or GET request?

Comment: The First  code contains info_id and Info(messages to be sent) that was passed in an array.  I used Post method and it was posted.   in the second code am trying to retrieve the info using info_id via get method but am having error "info_id" not found. it seems "info_id" is not submitted to enable message retrival

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `GET` method, I see you pass the `info_id` using post fields.

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data",
```

If you use `GET` method, usually data should be passed in URL params, not on post fields.

Better if you have the APIDOC, so we will know the params required for accessing `GET`.